# How to make iframe redirect with cookies

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, iframe, cross-domain

we are trying to integrate some service (MSDS), we use login URL + client guid, something like this "https://login.ehs.com/pl/[guid]"
this request's response has code 302 to redirect to another URL and returns with some cookies, the browser sets these cookies in the redirection request then it redirects again to the client's profile (successfully login),

What we want is to show this page in an **iframe** on our website, but we noticed that the redirection request is sent without the cookies returned from the first request, hence it renders back an error html page (error in logging in).

so how to allow this request and the redirection with setting header cookies when using the **iframe**?

here are the redirection request cookies when setting the URL in a chrome tab
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeU5U.jpg)

And those when using iframe
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxn2s.png)

**Note that our website domain is totally different than the integrated service domain.**

Comment: The browser might have blocked these cookies as third-party cookies, which is a common setting these days, or some privacy enhancing plugin might have eaten them (for the same reason.) If that is the root cause here, then this would require users to configure their browsers differently, resp. add expections for the domains in question in their browser/plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't access cross-origin cookies from a foreign domain. This thread is related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113187/accesssing-cookies-of-another-domain-using-iframes-and-javascript

I recommend you do the login request on your application itself instead of doing it from an iFrame, or at least modify the iFrame to send you back the cookies using postMessage and you can set them yourself in your page.